# Cannot set property 'Swiper' of undefined

Tags: javascript, npm, cdn, swiper.js

I just added the Swiper 4.0.2 from the cdnjs.
But as soon as I refresh the page, this error shows up on my console.

```
swiper.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Swiper' of undefined
```

This is swiper.js line 16:

```
13   (function (global, factory) {
14     typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
15     typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
16     (global.Swiper = factory());
17   }(this, (function () { 'use strict';
```

It seems that `global` is undefined.
Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: It is a Wordpress custom theme, quite a large file. I haven't done anything just importing from the CDN then this shows up. Obviously, all the other Swiper function is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically if you're still having this error. You just need to look onto your gulpfile.js under plugin.babel and look at the ignore section and just add swiper.js to the array.

```
.pipe(plugin.babel({
        presets: ['es2015'],
        compact: true,
        ignore: ['what-input.js','swiper.js']
    }))
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. I figured this out a while back. Thanks, Mikhail to update this.